# How can I smoothly connect 2 faces with a curve?

Tags: mesh

I'm making a stained glass window. I'm now at the point where I want to connect all the individual pipes with each other but I feel like I've tried everything and I just can't seem to get it to work.

[Here's a video of the problem and what I tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q524Y.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Suggest you investigate Blender's spin tool to get the rotation and then bridge edge loops when the alignment is close enough.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what kind of join you want. If you want a curved join you can do something as simple as the following. Select the two (2) [`Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) (without faces) and go to menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*. In the lower left corner where the operator options popup, increase the *Number of Cuts*.

[image]

If you want the pipes to have a sharper intersection and a rounded joined outer edge, you can do this, albeit more tedious, procedure:

Set the *Transform Orientation* to *Normal* and set the *Transform Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins*.

[image]

Make sure you're in *Edit Mode* and tick the *Auto Merge* checkbox and the *Split Edges & Faces* checkbox under *Active Tool and Workspace Settings*.

[image]

Select the two (2) [`Edge Loops`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) you want to merge and press <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to move the faces along their *Normals* until they fully intersect each other. Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

[image]

Press <kbd>K</kbd> to enable the [`Knife Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html) then individually click <kbd>LMB</kbd> on each vertex or click and drag through each vertex along the circular intersected section until you complete the loop and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the cut.

[image]

Now you can select the excess faces and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Faces*.

[image]

Press <kbd>K</kbd> again to enable the [`Knife Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html) and repeat the cutting procedure for the inner face intersection as shown:

[image]

Select the inner faces and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Faces*.

[image]

Select the hollow area's Edge Loop and press <kbd>F</kbd> to [`Fill Face`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/fill.html). Move the mouse away from the center. Press <kbd>i</kbd> to [`Inset Face`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) and slowly move towards the select face center. click <kbd>LMB</kbd> or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm. Hover over the face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to add a [`Loop Cut`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) and scroll your mouse forward to add several cuts.

[image]

Select the inner face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *> Cursor to Selected*. Set the *Transform Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor* and enable *Proportional Editing* and set the *Proportional Editing Falloff* to *Sphere*.

[image]

With the inner face selected press <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> to move along the normal and scroll your mouse wheel to adjust the amount of editing you need to get a nice curved surface.

[image]

Comment: very nice answer!!+1

Comment: thank you chris!! was a bit tedious to prepare though XD

Comment: I know - and often the OP doesn’t even appreciate it…and just writes comments because of his bad question…‍♂️

Comment: true! especially with low reputation. good thing is that my motivation to do this is for practice and a nice reference when i need it, as a matter of fact, i just discovered about the adding of cuts to curve the bridge edge loops just now :D

Comment: that's one reason why i am making tutorials. Because if you repeat stuff, you learn it yourself better. And you can even watch your own tutorials, if you forgot it (what already happened in my case :D) and you learn it even deeper because whenever you do it - you often discover new aspects

Comment: Now I know what you wanted the selection order for  :)

Comment: hahaha exactly! i wanted to quickly select the vertices in x-ray mode and press `j` but unfortunately that didn't work even when i selected them manually in order. `j` would only cut 1 pair of planes. funny thing is even with just 1 set of intersecting planes i would have to double tap `j` to cut it properly which was kinda weird. see image where the 2 vertices are shared by both planes: https://snipboard.io/h6PsfJ.jpg

Comment: Just a quick idea for a nicer rounded corner: fill the edge loop with F, extrude it a bit with E, scale it down with S to match the edge flow, then bevel with B: [round corner with bevel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nscUxYgEHxzaUa0M_4ZJtC-TwLVyLiK5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey that's even better! thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! I had some trouble with the edge loops, as well as the second way Harry showed, but I eventually made it work with the spin tool. Place the 3d cursor somewhere between the two pipes, and then select one of the faces, using the spin tool to first rotate the face so that it aligns with the other face, and the simply dragging the rotated face close to the other face, Bridge the two edge loops and done! It gave a really nice looking result.

Answer (score 1):

You did good by connecting them but before that you should rotate the faces in each others' direction. Select one face then  apply shear(click <kbd>F3</kbd> > Type "Shear"), after that connect the two faces as you did before and apply a single edge loop, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to Smoothened it out.

[image]